# Google Analytics dropping records?

Tags: google-analytics

I published larger number of messages to Google Analytics ( around ~25 million ).

This was few days ago so there's plenty of time for GA to index these records.

When I check on GA, it's missing few thousand records. I'm just curious if anyone else has experienced this issue when you published large volume of messages to GA.

GA specs: Analytics 360, publishing events

Comment: What do you mean by messages? Hits to the measurement protocoll?

Comment: that's right. hits

Comment: Your question is still quite broad. Is this a free or a 360 property? What type of hits are these? Pageviews, events, timing hits, ecommerce data?

Comment: This is analytics 360. Hits are events